# Splitting background colors

Tags: css

I'm trying to split the background color of a `div` - I want the left side to be white, the right side to be black. I tried using a wrapper `div` with two divs nested inside it, but the black div doesn't fill the wrapper div 100% like I need it to.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nP8Qq/2/

Comment: @NullPointer - I think in HTML5, the `p` closing tag is optional, right? As well as `</li>`? (Not saying it shouldn't be included, I do...)

Comment: Yeah, and the code in that fiddle is just pseudo-code so I could post it real quick, it doesn't affect the problem I'm seeing here :P

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nP8Qq/3/ Note, that will go down in flames in IE7, which doesn't support `display: table-*`.

Comment: Change the `width` of `#content` to `50%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/nP8Qq/10/

I added colors to the divs so you can see where they are.
I colored the background div so if the black div isn't tall enough, you will not be able to tell.

I added the missing closing tags `<p>Content</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm not answering for why your code is not working (the solution by Steve  Wellens is perfect) . I'm suggesting a *possibly* more elegant solution to having multiple color backgrounds: **Linear Gradient with Color-stop**.

You can apply a linear gradient across your `div` , and since you want multiple colors (in this case 2), you can specify a `color-stop`. With a `color-stop`, you can specify where along the line of gradient you want your new color to begin, with a `percentage`. Specifying 50% will begin your new color at exactly halfway of the linear gradient.

You can play around with the percentages until you get your desired effect.

Check out the following, they have achieved what you're trying to do, with gradients:

[Linear Gradients/color-stop](http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/css3/gradient.html)

[Linear Gradient reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)

[CSS Tricks - color-stop](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)

Check if it's useful for you.

Comment: That's an interesting trick - I'll definitely try that out in the future.